# Updating Meta Tag in GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, react-helmet

I want to use [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) with Gatsby.  On the [usage page](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/usage/#responsive-meta-tag), it says I have to add the following responsive meta tag:

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
/>
```

Now, if I take a look at the meta tags that Gatsby starts off with, they are **almost** the same:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

So basically,, the only difference is that `material-ui` wants me to add `minimum-scale=1`.

My question is how can I **update** or **replace**the meta viewport tag to include this value.  I tried using [react-helmelt](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) in my base layout as follows:

```
<Helmet>
  <meta 
    name='viewport'
    content='minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no'
  />
</Helmet>
```

But what that does is give me **two** meta viewport tags -- the one that Gatsby starts out with and the one that I added via Helmet:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no' />
```

What I want is just one meta viewport tag -- the one that includes `minimum-scale=1`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really need the viewport meta changed you will need to override the default html template Gatsby uses. Just copy `.cache/default-html.js` to `src/html.js` and customize it to your liking.

As a side note, I really doubt there will be any problem using Gatsby's default viewport meta with Material-UI.

Comment: @Moshe This is the correct method, and regarding the tag duplication issue, check this https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/341